# How I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL method should work?

Tags: react-native

I tried to find out what actually this method do but in official documentation no info

> import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
>
> I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(true);

Comment: here docs are telling more about it 
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/11/06/react-native-monthly-5#facebook